# Inconsistent behavior when use Solr boosting

Tags: solr, content-search, boosting

I'm using Sitecore 9.3 and Solr 8.1.1, I have this simple query

```
q=itemName_t:(*test*)^80&fl=itemName_t,_templateID,score&fq=_indexname:(custom_index)&wt=xml
```

And these are the results:

- item1 , templateID : template1ID, score : 80
- item2 , templateID : template1ID, score : 80
- item3 , templateID : template2ID, score : 80
- item4 , templateID : template2ID, score : 80
- item5 , tempalteID : tempalte3ID, score : 80

The results are mix of multiple templates, I wanted to boost only two templates types which are template1 and template2,
So I wrote this query:

```
q=(_template:(**template1ID**)^60 OR _template:(**template2ID**)^60) AND itemName_t:(*test*)^80&fl=itemName_t,_templateID,score&fq=_indexname:(custom_index)&wt=xml
```

The results became like this:

- item3 , templateID : template2ID, score : 215
- item4 , templateID : template2ID, score : 215
- item1 , templateID : template1ID, score : 90
- item2 , templateID : template1ID, score : 90
- item5 , tempalteID : tempalte3ID, score : 80

Although I boosted the two templates with the same value, template2 was boosted more higher than template1.

I enabled the solr explanation, but couldn't understand it.

Comment: We’ll need some clarification on a few things: 1. What are you attempting achieve with boosting? 2. Does the phrase `test` show up in any of the result item names? 3. Can you update your question to include the explain results from Solr?

Comment: @ChetCheeto
I'm trying to boost two types of templates, as I have multiple templates at the search results.
"test" is included at the item title always, it's at all the search results.

Comment: I need to mention that template1 has 855 items and template2 has only 8 items.

Comment: Are you using Solr Cloud?

Comment: @MarcelGruber yes I'm

Comment: If you run the query on each of your individual nodes, do they all return the same results?

Comment: @mohamed-yaseen - I am trying to achieve something similar to boost results from a specific template on top. Sitecore 10.1.2 with Solr 8.4
This is my query: /select?q=title_t:(*charcoal*)+AND+_language:en-US &bq:_template:<templateID>^5 I get the matching 9 results but boosting the results with templateID on top is not happening.Am I missing anything in the query? Were you able to find out a solution for this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GajalakshmiGovindarajan
I apologize for my late reply, but I didn't reach a solution for my case.

Answer (score 0):

The above query seems to be correct and the results also come as expected.
Also would like to highlight that score is calculated not only based on the template only.

As I can see there are other parameters as well combined in boosting query, I would suggest having a look at the score formula on each result.

Please take [solr debugger chrome extension](https://browser-addons.com/solr-query-debugger/) - to get score. Hope this will help.

Comment: The solr debugger extension is removed.
I've looked at the score formula, but still didn't get the full idea.

Comment: Add the score formula to your question, please.